Best approach to n-to-m relations between entities
I am trying to build a Drupal 10 site that has a library of books with poems. Each book has a title, ISBN and other data and a list of the poems included in the book. The list shows the title and the page number of each poem.
So far I can create a Content type Book with additional fields and a Content type Poem with additional fields. In the Book type I can create an Entity Reference to Poem.
However, a poem can be published in multiple books and in each book it has a different page number.
If the user selects a poem it should see a list of books it appears in with the page number in the respective book.
I have the information in a SQL database, a table for Book, a table for Poem and a table for PoemInBook.
What is the best way to create these relationships in a Drupal site?

How i'd probably do it is:

Create a "Book poems" (or some other logical name) paragraph type
Add a entity reference field to your Poem content type e.g. field_poem
Add a page number field so the user can enter the page number
Add this paragraph as an unlimited field on the Book content type

So effectively a user can create a book and then create as many "book poem" paragraph items as they want
Then probably with custom code to display this information when someone views a poem you'd need to:

Get all paragraphs referencing the poem in question via "field_poem"
Then look at the parent entity ID that's referencing this paragraph.
load that parent ID and this is the book


Thanks for the response. This is a common approach, but I wonder if it also allows for a list of all the books and the respective page numbers on a page that shows the book. I see the Paragraphs module as a kind of structured text while I am looking for a structured data approach.

I've tried all kinds of approaches, but this one works best.
